# How to prepare my laptop (dell inspiron 17 r se 7720) for the clean installation of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop

I am very much satisfied with the solution provided by Mr. Manuel Quijada about the installation of windows 7 on my dell inspiron 17 r se 7720 which came along with intel rapid storage technology but the thing that's bothering me is the bios setup which i don't know how to set. I want to know the things like boot mode (UEFI or else), sata operation mode (AHCI, ATA OR Intel rapid storage technology), boot list option and what to enable and what to disable in order to prepare it for the installation. Just help me with this issue and tell me all the steps (because i have not mentioned all of them).

Comment: "solution provided by Mr. Manuel Quijada" it would help if you provided a link to this.

Comment: You need to provide more detailed information about the options in your bios.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the defaults are fine. It depends on what your BIOS/UEFI supports. I feel you might not fully understand what they actually refer to, so a few definitions for you:

**[UEFI / BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)**

UEFI is the newer 'firmware' replacing BIOS, providing a layer between your operating system and the platform it runs on. This is, put extremely simply, where your systems devices are investigated and pre-operating system settings are set.

Now, where you'll be getting confused with the boot mode is how this new system works. Where as before, a hard drive had to have a MBR ([Master Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)) written to the start of a disk, that is no longer the case. Instead, a single [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) can contain all your boot entries in EFI files. This uses the newer [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) instead, and it's a lot easier to work with with far less limitation. Your options would be to boot with EFI, or Legacy mode (the old MBR style). Windows 7 supports both, I believe it came out around the time EFI was coming into play. It's your choice, but for better compatibility if you plan to upgrade to Windows 10, I'd choose EFI.

**[AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) / [ATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) / [Intel RST](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html)**

These are interfaces for your storage devices. ATA is an older standard, used on the old Parallel ribbon cable style devices. This option is only provided for compatibility reasons for older OS support really and should almost never be used (if anyone has another opinion on this, please let me know!).

Now, Intel RST vs AHCI is really your choice. AHCI is the standard, it's the most compatible with modern OS's and easiest to set up with SATA devices, requiring no additional drivers or work to get working. Intel RST is Intel's take on it, with a lot of power user and device monitoring options, great for [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) options if you don't have a dedicated RAID card. As it is, you're installing on a laptop, so this really isn't needed, and as I'm assuming you aren't fully understanding what it is, I wouldn't worry about it. In your position, I'd choose AHCI.

You also mention 'boot list option'. This is probably where you choose the boot priority order. Whilst you're installing Windows, set this so your DVD/CD drive, or USB device if you're installing from USB, is first. After this should be your hard drive. Once Windows is installed you can set this so your HDD is first.

Really though, the manufacturer will have made all these decisions for you and will provide all the drivers and information you need on [their site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-17r-se-7720/drivers). As such, I'd take this post as a chance to learn what is what, but simply reset your UEFI/BIOS settings back to the manufacturer defaults and install Windows 7. There isn't a magical setting that'll make your machine much better, and typical users won't ever need to touch it.